# how to get all immediate descendants of a node in closure table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an assignment in Uni about SQL databases and I am pretty terrible at it.
Right now, I am tasked with creating a tree database structure (by using the closure table model, as the title would suggest)
My tree is made out of two tables: one is the table containing the nodes themselves, the other contains all the paths from all ancestors to all descendants.
In other words, it is something like this (I used sqlite, though I doubt it is important to the question itself, but just in case):

```
  CREATE TABLE Nodes(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 name TEXT);
 CREATE TABLE Paths(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 ancestor INTEGER,
 descendant INTEGER,
 FOREIGN KEY (ancestor) REFERENCES Nodes (id),
 FOREIGN KEY (descendant) REFERENCES Nodes (id));
```

Where the table Paths contains all ordered pairs (ancestor, descendant) such that there's a path from ancestor to descendant in the tree, including all paths where ancestor = descendant.
My task (which I am splendidly failing) is to write such a query that would get me all direct descendants of a node.
I have tried to do it for about two hours now and I am still at a dead end.
I have also tried adding attribute pathLength to the paths table that would tell the number of nodes between ancestor and descendant but the teacher didn't let me do that.

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how, here's my answer to those who may face a similar problem. I know the query may look terrible, but that's the best I can give you now.

```
select descendant from paths where descendant in (select descendant from paths group by descendant having count(ancestor) = (select count(ancestor) from paths where descendant = **{your node}**) + 1) and ancestor = **{your node}**;
```